# A homotopy equivalence between total spaces in a (Hurewicz) fibration which is not a fiber homotopy equivalence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fibration

In Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book it is noted after 4.61 that:

fiber preserving map + homotopy equivalence $\Rightarrow$  fiber homotopy equivalence.

### Question:

Could there be two fibrations over the **same** base space where the total spaces ***are*** homotopy equivalent, but there is **no** fiber homotopy equivalence  between them?  (and therefore also no fiber preserving map)

If so, I would be glad to have a simple example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can fiber a circle over a circle in many ways.

Comment: Could you please give some more detail?

Comment: A two to one map (covering space) from circle to circle is a fibration, in which every fiber has two points. The identity map is another, in which every fiber has one point.

Answer (score 3):

Let X be any non-contractible space. Let the base of your fibration be the disjoint union of countably many copies of X and countably many copies of the point. Let one fibration be the identity and the other be the identity over every component but one point; put X above that point. The two spaces are both abstractly homeomorphic to the base, but a fiber homotopy equivalence would have to be a homotopy equivalence between X and the point over that particular component.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of such examples, but here is the simplest one I know. Let $M_{p,q}$ be the total space of the principal circle bundle over $S^2\times S^2$ with Euler class 
$(p, q)$.

If $p,q$ are relatively prime, then it is known that $M_{p,q}$ is diffeomorphic to $S^2\times S^3$. Namely, Smale proved in his paper
["On the structure of 5-manifolds"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970417)
 that the diffeomorphism type of closed, simply-connected, spin 5-manifolds is determined by the second cohomology which is $\mathbb Z$ for $M_{p,q}$ and also for $S^2\times S^3$. (If you have trouble showing $M_{p,q}$ satisfies the above conditions, see Wang-Ziller's paper
 ["Einstein metrics
on principal torus bundles."](http://www.intlpress.com/JDG/archive/1990/31-1-215.pdf)

On the other hand, the fiber homotopy equivalence in this case preserves the Euler class
(up to sign).

Answer (score 0):

I think James-Whitehead are quite relevant:

MR0068836 Reviewed James, I. M.; Whitehead, J. H. C. The homotopy theory of sphere bundles over spheres. II. Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 5, (1955). 148–166.

MR0061838 Reviewed James, I. M.; Whitehead, J. H. C. The homotopy theory of sphere bundles over spheres. I. Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 4, (1954). 196–218.